# Occaisonal 0s timeout with Protractor / Angular

Tags: angularjs, protractor

About 50% of the time, the first test in our suite of Protractor tests fails with the following error:

```
Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 0ms
```

So, we updated the `protractor.conf.js` to explicitly include some sensible timeouts:

```
exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9001',
  specs: ['e2e/website.spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox'
  },
  getPageTimeout: 10000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 10000,
```

We still get timeouts on the first test, but this time with some arbitrarily low number, rather than 0ms:

```
Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 15ms.
Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 1ms.
```

The exact line it times-out on is:

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('/#/signout');
    browser.waitForAngular(); // Timeout here.
  });
```

Comment: Does it 100% angular page?

Comment: It is definitely an Angular page. The exact same code is run on subsequent test runs, and they all pass. The problem is only occasional, so seems like some race condition from Protractor (although I'm not denying we may be using it incorrectly and that is causing the race condition - but from what I can see we're not doing anything out of the ordinary!)

Answer (score 1):

We found the culprit: `'angular-loading-bar'`

After removing this from our project, the issue went away.